# Code removes repeat letters from dictionary

Tags: python

My code is supposed to print a dictionary containing the letters of the input (`s`), and assign each character a random number within a certain length (the length of `s`). When it tries to add a letter that is already in the string, it skips it, but it's not supposed to.

My code:

```py
import random as r
def strhash(s):
  x = 0
  y = 0
  z = 0
  ind = {
    }
  ra = 0
  while z != len(s):
    ra = r.randint(0, len(s))
    x += 1
    y = x-1
    ind[s[y:x]] = ra
    z += 1
  return ind

print(strhash('hello'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a dictionary key should be unique. You can use other datatype maybe list of tuples
For example

```py
from random import randint

def strhash(s):
  result = []
  l = len(s)
  for i in s:
    result.append((i, randint(0, l)))
  return result

print(strhash('hello'))
```

Output:

```
[('h', 1), ('e', 5), ('l', 5), ('l', 5), ('o', 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use a different data type than a dictionary. I wanted it to be a dictionary so I could easily convert it into `JSON` but I will find another way.

Answer (score 1):

a dictionary cannot have multiple same values for a key(one alphabet in your case)
so it is gonna skip.

Comment: can you help me fix it?

Comment: have a look at Joaquin's answer below that can be an alternative

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
ind[s[y:x]] = ra
```

This is not the way to asing a key to a dict, in the code below you can see how you should add a new key

```
import random as r
    def strhash(s):
      x , z , y = 0, 0 ,0
      ind = {}
      ra = 0
      while z != len(s):
        ra = r.randint(0, len(s))
        print(s[z])
        ind[s[z]] = ra
        z += 1
      return ind
    
    
    print(strhash('hello'))
```

Output:

```
{'e': 3, 'l': 5, 'h': 3, 'o': 1}
```

Comment: You could explain why OP's code doesn't work as well.

Comment: This doesnt solve OP's problem though does it? It looks like they want each letter in `s` to have a random value assigned to it, regardless of if that letter repeats. In your example, theres only one `l` in the returned dictionary while there are two in `hello`. The only way to make his code work is to use a data type that isnt dict as @ParasGupta mentioned in his answer